# Can I Cleave during an Attack of Opportunity and then attack with a Readied action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, actions

Is this situation possible?

- I have Cleave
- I have readied an action to attack
- Someone on horseback charges me, and provokes an attack of opportunity from me
- I take the Attack of Opportunity, attack and kill the horse
- Can I then Cleave the rider?
- After cleaving, can I then *also* take my readied attack action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this all works. Some notes:

- In order for the rider to provoke from you, they must *leave* a square you threaten. Unless your reach is greater than theirs, that won’t happen on a charge (a charger *must* attack from the first available square, and stop there), and probably won’t happen on other attacks (wandering around inside someone’s threatened area is something people don’t usually do).

  Your original question referred to the rider as a “lancer” – if you
  meant “someone wielding a lance” by this, note that the lance has
  reach, which will make it more difficult to outreach them.
- Both the rider and horse provoke in this situation. I had to double-check this, but the requirement for provoking is

  > Moving out of a threatened square

  It doesn’t seem to matter if you move under your own power or not.
- You didn’t ask, but for the record, whether Combat Reflexes would allow you to attack both horse and rider is debatable. Combat Reflexes says this:

  > This feat does not let you make more than one attack for a given opportunity, but if the same opponent provokes two attacks of opportunity from you, you could make two separate attacks of opportunity (since each one represents a different opportunity).

  It is unclear if the rider and the horse provoking count as the same opportunity or not.
- Cleave works off of *any* attack. As long as your attack makes a creature drop, and you have not already used Cleave this round, you get that extra attack immediately, period.
- The attack of opportunity is completely resolved before anything else happens. That includes your readied action. Once it has resolved, it has no effect on any future actions (aside from your ability to take another attack of opportunity later in that round).
- A readied action requires a condition of some sort. There are many here that could work, but you still must have one of them. Note that, depending on the wording, the readied action might come *before* the attack of opportunity – for instance, if you readied an action to attack someone “as soon as they came into range,” that would occur before the attack of opportunity (since they only provoke the attack of opportunity *after leaving* a square you threaten).

  Under normal circumstances, the order wouldn’t matter (you could use your readied action against the horse, Cleave into the rider, and then take your attack of opportunity against the rider assuming he continued moving), but if you were setting against a charge, your readied action (only) gets double damage, so it might be desirable to try to save that for the rider.

  To get that order you want, you would have to choose a condition that allows you to attack after the attack of opportunity. This could literally be “when he or she leaves a square I threaten,” the same condition that provoked in the first place. D&D doesn’t have detailed rules for the timing of simultaneously-triggered actions, but since they are both yours, I’d be very surprised if any DM balked at letting you decide that order yourself. If necessary, you could probably get away with a condition of “after I’ve taken an attack of opportunity against them.” But remember that all of these triggering conditions must be worked out with your DM.
- The rules don’t actually say that killing a mount foils a charge, but one would kind of expect it to. I suggest going over this plan with the DM ahead of time, and determining what he thinks of that. This might nix the double-damage you may have gotten for setting against a charge.

Comment: Ok to help clarify a few points I forgot to mention, The DM has created these "lancers" in a very hard to recreate way. They have feats that allow the lance to do more damage off of a charge, have insane AC or are just impossible to hit (someone got a 35 to hit and it didn't hit), and continue moving after their attack (they follow through their entire charge distance), also stuns don't last long at all they wear off before they are supposed to. Any idea what the build is or how to deal with them without the extra hp pool of the horse (knocking them off their mount perhaps)?

Comment: @Barroth All of these things are definitely *possible* (there are many charge-damage-boosting feats, AC is fairly easy to come by if you need it, and the continued movement is no doubt from Ride-by Attack. Shrugging off stuns could be a number of things, particularly if they were actively healing them somehow (magic item, spell, etc.). There’s too many ways to maybe do that to guess exactly what’s going on. But you can also ask a question about tactics for those enemies.